# How to confirm before action in admingrid magento2?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent

Here is my code:

```
<?php
namespace Tatva\Unsubscribepaypal\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\TatvaUnsubscribeListing;

class PageActions extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource["data"]["items"])) {
            foreach ($dataSource["data"]["items"] as & $item) {
                $name = $this->getData("name");
                $id = "X";
                if(isset($item["customer_id"]))
                {
                    $id = $item["customer_id"];
                }
                //echo $id; exit;
                $item[$name]["view"] = [
                "href"=>$this->getContext()->getUrl(
                    "unsubscribetco/index/unsubscribe",["customer_id"=>$id]),
                "label"=>__("Unsubscribe"),
                'confirm' => [
                'title' => __('Unsubscribe ${ $.$data.title }'),
                'message' => __('Are you sure?')
                ]
                ];
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }    

}
```

here is my action code:

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Tatva\Unsubscribetco\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\TatvaUnsubscribeListing\PageActions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try below code:**

```
$item[$name] = [
    'view' => [
        'href' => $this->getContext()->getUrl(
                "unsubscribetco/index/unsubscribe",["customer_id"=>$id]),
        'label' => __('Unsubscribe'),
        'confirm' => [
            'title' => __('Unsubscribe ${ $.$data.title }'),
            'message' => __('Are you sure?')
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: No,it's still not working?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra is it throwing any error?

Comment: No it's redirecting directly without confirm prompt.

Comment: try after clearing cache and run setup:upgrade command

Comment: still not working.. i have added actioncolumn code please check if i have make any mistake over there

Comment: Why do you have different Module Name in actionColumn class and PageAction file ?

Comment: actually this is working

Comment: Es there a way a to add also an input?